# How to connect Django 3.1 to MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb

I am working with Django 3.1 edition. As a Database, my choice is to go with any NoSQL database like MongoDB. I have tried two ways to connect MongoDB with Django 3.1. First One is using Djongo and the Second one is using Mongo Engine. But both the cases, I am unable to work with Django 3.1. In the case of Django, it's not supporting Django 3.1 but it switching me to Django 3.0.5, and in the case of mongo engine it's not supporting Django 3.1. Is there any third way to connect MongoDB with Django 3.1. Note that I have to use **Django 3.1** only

These are the docs I was following in Djongo and Mongo Engine.

**https://pypi.org/project/djongo/**

**https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html**

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re using MongoDB with a fresh project on a framework designed for traditional RDBMS’s? One option is to use a supported DB like Postgres for your default DB, and Mongo as a secondary DB connection. If you’re looking for indexed JSON in a column, Postgres does that too: the best of all worlds.

Comment: Actually, I an not the project leader. I have told to find out the way to connect Django 3.1 with MongoDB. I will be greatly benefited if you can tell me the way to do this. (of-course if there is any way at all...)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is going to be Djongo:

https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/

However, Djongo's `master` branch currently supports up to Django 3.0.5. If you *really* need Django 3.1 support:

- Clone the Djongo repository
- Change this line to have an upper bounds of `<3.2` instead of `<=3.0.5`: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/blob/de5191ccbd9dd2255627e6d1cb6a58cd591c2353/setup.py#L86
- `pip install -e .` from the cloned directory into your venv.

Then see if it works, and what needs fixing. If you fix things in Djongo, you can send Pull Requests to the project for 3.1 support.

Please note, this is a fairly risky dependency to put into a project. You'll be locked to using versions of Django that Djongo supports going forward, and won't be able to upgrade until Djongo does. I've had to do this in some of my projects with third-party SQL Server support, and it can be frustrating. I wouldn't recommend it if you aren't comfortable getting involved with the project you're relying on, and contributing. That said... good luck!